# SSO taskpane is not configured properly

Tags: javascript, outlook, es6-promise, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to make a Office Addin with single sign on . i also have used Azure AD for that and enable the conditions for reference please refer the screenshot below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2duIF.png)

but when command is given and authenticated properly this returns me an error .

please refer to the mentioned below screenshot .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIDZ.png)

Comment: Be aware of upcoming changes in SSO - [New Single Sign-on service for Office Add-ins rolling out in Office on the web](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/new-single-sign-on-service-for-office-add-ins-rolling-out-in-office-on-the-web/)

Answer (score 1):

Your Error is due to unhandled promise which means that there is some async code that you have not written in try catch block and that particular promise is not resolved/handled correctly. My suggestion would be to use trace unhandled package to trace where exactly your error is arising.

Trace Unhandled: https://www.npmjs.com/package/trace-unhandled

Comment: however it throwed an error but problem is solved as some cache problems were there thats why